# Nest a Json in Speech Marks

Tags: json

I have a JSON that I'd like to nest into another JSON. Is this possible? Problem I'm facing is when I add Json #2 to #1 is gives me a formatting error.

JSON #1:
`{"home":"This a sentence about home", "json":"<ADD JSON HERE>"}`

JSON #2:

```
{
    "homepage": {
        "heading": [
            {"h1":"Sentence for H1!"},
            {"description":"Description about us"},
            {"button1":"Learn More"},
        ],
}
```

What I've tried:

`{"home":"This a sentence about home", "json":" { "homepage": {"heading": [ {"h1":"Sentence for H1!"},{"description":"Description about us"},{"button1":"Learn More"},],}"}`

Comment: What code did you try?

Comment: I've updated my question to show you what I've already tried

Comment: Did you have a particular language in mind or just how to format JSON this way in general?  If so, tag the language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second JSON isn't valid (extra commas and missing `}`), but this is:

```json
{
    "homepage": {
        "heading": [
            {"h1":"Sentence for H1!"},
            {"description":"Description about us"},
            {"button1":"Learn More"}
        ]
    }
}
```

To embed it as a string, backslash-escape the embedded double-quotes:

```json
{
  "home": "This a sentence about home",
  "json": "{\"homepage\": {\"heading\": [{\"h1\": \"Sentence for H1!\"}, {\"description\": \"Description about us\"}, {\"button1\": \"Learn More\"}]}}"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

(If you are using JavaScript)

If you pass JSON to JSON.stringify it will escape your JSON.

You can then insert the escaped JSON in to your original JSON.

So:

```
 const jsonToInsert = {
    "homepage": {
       "heading": [
           {"h1":"Sentence for H1!"},
           {"description":"Description about us"},
           {"button1":"Learn More"}
       ]
     }
 };
 const stringifiedJson = JSON.stringify(jsonToInsert);
 const completeJson = {"home":"This a sentence about home", "json": stringifiedJson}
```

This should work.

Comment: Ah yes you are correct, I have assumed OP is using JavaScript.